# Assign to read-only property by ngModel

Tags: angular

I have next array:

```
items: [{ name: string }]
```

In the html file I wrote this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.name"/>
</div>
```

but when I'm editing it I get error:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'text' of object '[object Object]'

I know solution with use other custom component instead div with @Input item, but i want do it only in single file.

Comment: how does the items array look like?

Comment: @Akora, i wrote it in top of topic, my array has items with property 'name' (string), I and want that ngModel work with this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-bbzj1o

I just added the following data:

```
this.items = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}];
```

Comment: oh yeah, u are right, my bad, just i getted my items from other component whtch set as read only, thanks.